# Querying Flask-SQLAlchemy through two table joins

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I've got three tables (for a sport-related application): Rounds, Games and Leagues.

I want to find the most recent Round for a League. To do that I need find the most recent Game and find what Round it is in.

In my Models Rounds have many Games and Rounds have a League but there is no direct relationship between Games and Leagues.

Here's my models simplified:

```
class Round(db.Model):
    """Round Model."""

    __tablename__ = 'rounds'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    order = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    league_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('leagues.id'))

    league = db.relationship('League', backref='rounds')


class Game(db.Model):
    """Game model."""

    __tablename__ = "games"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    utc_time = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    round_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('rounds.id'))

    round = db.relationship('Round', backref="games")


class League(db.Model):
    """League Model."""

    __tablename__ = 'leagues'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name, abbreviation, other_names):
        self.name = name
```

How do I query Games with a round.league condition?

I'm thinking something like this, but it isn't working:

```
game = Game.query.join(Round).join(League).filter(
        Game.utc_time < datetime.utcnow(),
        League.id == league.id
    ).order_by(Game.utc_time.desc()).first()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After pouring over the SQLAlchemy documentation for many hours the solution was simply that I needed to be more explicit when defining my joins. I suppose the table joins weren't obvious to SQLAlchemy for some reason.

Instead of just `join(League)` I had to tell it where to join `join(League, Round.league_id == League.id)`

The query ended up looking like this:

```
game = Game.query.join(Round).join(
    League, Round.league_id == League.id
).filter(
    Game.utc_time < datetime.utcnow(),
    League.id == league.id
).order_by(Game.utc_time.desc()).first()
```

Comment: So no need for the foreign key mapping then I guess

Comment: From the query object can i create a schema for it, I want the result to get a dictionary as the final output?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a relationship between `League` and `Round`.

```
class League(db.Model):
    (...)
    db.relationship("Round", backref='league')
    (...)
```

Your query should work after adding that to your `League` model.

Comment: Thanks @AArias. Annoyingly for everyone, I do have that relationship in there, just on the Round model (exactly the same only reversed). My apologies, I accidentally deleted that line when editing the question and have added it back in now.

Comment: Mm. Did you try reversing both relations declarations? Try declaring the League-Round relationship in the league model (as in my code example) and the Round-Game one in the Round model. I can't try it right now cos I'm on my phone but at least in the sqlalchemy examples for one to many relationships the relationship is declared in the parent model: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many let me know if that works and I'll update the answer

Comment: Also, leave `league_id` and `round_id` as they are.

Comment: Hi @AArias, I did. See my solution above - I'd been meaning to update this for a couple of days now. I tried your suggestions but ultimately my solution is what got me over the line.